# Conversion between two generic lists using reflection

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Is there a way to make the following method shorter (and safer, in terms of extending enumeration)?

```
private object MakeTypedList(IReadOnlyList<IData> readOnlyList, DataTypes dataTypes)
{
    switch (dataTypes)
    {
        case DataTypes.Byte:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IByteData>();
        case DataTypes.Integer:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IIntegerData>();
        case DataTypes.Float:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IFloatData>();
        case DataTypes.Boolean:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IBooleanData>();
        case DataTypes.String:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IStringData>();
        case DataTypes.ByteArray:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IByteArray>();
        case DataTypes.IntegerArray:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IIntegerArray>();
        case DataTypes.FloatArray:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IFloatArray>();
        case DataTypes.BooleanArray:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IBooleanArray>();
        case DataTypes.StringArray:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IStringArray>();
        case DataTypes.List:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IListData>();
        case DataTypes.Image24:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IImage24>();
        case DataTypes.Image8:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IImage8>();
        case DataTypes.FloatSignal:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IFloatSignal>();
        case DataTypes.IntegerSignal:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IIntegerSignal>();
        case DataTypes.Record:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IRecord>();
        case DataTypes.Raw:
            return readOnlyList
                .Cast<IRaw>();
        default:
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("Unsupported DataType!");
    }
}
```

**Note:** The header must remain unchanged, because these are the data I can provide to this method. This is the result of much complicated architecture and cannot be changed. I can, however, manipulate - for instance - the enumeration itself or the interfaces (eg. add attributes etc.)

---

A different way to ask the same question. Is it possible to cast `List<Base>` to `List<Derived>` if I have a `Type` variable containing object representing the `Derived` type?

```
List<Base> b;
Type t = typeof(Derived)
object derivedList = // use t only to construct List<Derived>
```

Comment: Note, `MakeTypedList` does not return a typed list, it returns a typed IEnumerable.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, but it's OK. It may be IEnumerable as well.

Comment: You might be able to use [`[DisplayName]`](http://geeksharp.com/2011/11/02/power-up-your-enumerations/) or some other similar attribute on your enum to hold the full name of the types, you could then use reflection to use the attribute and then use reflection to call the appropriate cast method. This is just an idea, not a full implementation, so posting as a comment. If you do write it up on your own feel free to answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is quite ugly, and this is certainly not shorter or more performant than what you wrote already, but it will make it more extensible.

First, define an attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class DataTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DataTypeAttribute(DataTypes dataType)
    {
        DataType = dataType;
    }

    public DataTypes DataType { get; private set; }
}
```

Then tag your interfaces with it:

```
[DataType(DataTypes.Byte)]
public interface IByteData : IData
{
}

[DataType(DataTypes.Integer)]
public interface IIntegerData : IData
{
}

// etc...
```

Note that I'm working off the assumption that all your individual data types inherit from the `IData` type.  (If not, they probably should.)

Now you can implement your `MakeTypedList` method as follows:

```
private object MakeTypedList(IReadOnlyList<IData> readOnlyList, DataTypes dataTypes)
{
    var type = typeof(IData).Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsInterface && typeof (IData).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .FirstOrDefault(t =>
        {
            var attribute = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataTypeAttribute), false)
                .FirstOrDefault() as DataTypeAttribute;
            return attribute != null && attribute.DataType == dataTypes;
        });

    if (type == null)
        throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("Unsupported DataType!");

    var enumerable = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethod("OfType", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] {readOnlyList});

    // you can omit this last step if you just want an IEnumerable<T>
    var list = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethod("ToList", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { enumerable });

    return list;
}
```

See - ugly.

Note that I used `OfType` instead of `Cast`.  This will filter the list to the type desired instead of throwing an exception when it encounters an item that doesn't belong the the type requested.  If you actually do want the exception to be thrown, just change `"OfType"` back to `"Cast"`.

Also note that for this to work, all of the data type interfaces must be in the same assembly as the `IData` interface.

Regarding the second example you gave, you can write a similar extension method:

```
public static object Cast<TBase>(this IEnumerable<TBase> original, Type type)
{
    return typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { original });
}
```

Which makes it simple to use with the variables you provided, like so:

```
List<Base> b;
Type t = typeof(Derived);

object derivedList = b.Cast(t);
```

Comment: I can use the second version, because I can do the opposite: instead of tagging interfaces with `DataTypes`, I can tag `DataTypes` with appropriate `typeof()`'s - thus quickly receiving required type. In my API these are very closely related, so I can simply use this solution. Indeed reflection is quite ugly, but surely your solution will be a lot more flexible than mine current one. Thanks!